# Why are these javascript files with my typescript files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Heres my tsconfig and basically there are so many duplicate js files of my tsx files.if there is a file called A.tsx there is an A.js with it and so on.
I believe this happened after i changed some stuffs in the tsconfig.I dont want these files in my folder.Can anyone help?I am new to typescript and i am having a hard time.

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: You're looking for an option like "output directory"

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Is that *really* your tsconfig?

Comment: check now.......

Comment: I created a new empty project with that tsconfig, npm installed typescript and @types/node, and a file with some dummy content at src/index.ts. Then I ran `npx ts-node src/index.ts` and it ran fine, then I ran `tsc src/index.ts` and sure enough it created index.js in the source directory. I don't know why it's ignoring your outDir in your tsconfig, but you can force it by adding `--outDir ./build` to the tsc command when you run it. Check your npm scripts in package.json